# Error while sending documents from the download folder (No such file or directory)

Tags: android, kotlin, file-upload

I am getting the error " Error: /storage/emulated/0/Download/1585730303.6972.pdf (No such file or directory)".I can't send documents such as  1585730303.6972.pdf .

Here i shared the code . Please check it.

```
            if (isDownloadsDocument(uri)) {
                    val AndroidVersion = Build.VERSION.RELEASE
                    Log.d("android_version",AndroidVersion)
                    if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.M) {
                        val id: String
                        var cursor: Cursor? = null
                        try {
                            cursor = context.contentResolver.query(uri, arrayOf(MediaStore.MediaColumns.DISPLAY_NAME), null, null, null)
                            if (cursor != null && cursor.moveToFirst()) {
                                val fileName = cursor.getString(0)
                                val path = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().toString() + "/Download/" + fileName

                                Log.d("orginal_path",path)

                                if (!TextUtils.isEmpty(path)) {
                                    return path
                                }
                            }
                        } finally {
                            cursor?.close()
                        }
                        id = DocumentsContract.getDocumentId(uri)
                        if (!TextUtils.isEmpty(id)) {
                            if (id.startsWith("raw:")) {
                                return id.replaceFirst("raw:".toRegex(), "")
                            }
                            val contentUriPrefixesToTry = arrayOf(
                                    "content://downloads/public_downloads",
                                    "content://downloads/my_downloads"
                            )
                            for (contentUriPrefix in contentUriPrefixesToTry) {
                                return try {
                                    val contentUri = ContentUris.withAppendedId(Uri.parse(contentUriPrefix), java.lang.Long.valueOf(id))
                                    Log.d("orginal_content_uri", contentUri.toString())
                                    /*   final Uri contentUri = ContentUris.withAppendedId(
                                                            Uri.parse("content://downloads/public_downloads"), Long.valueOf(id));*/
                                    getDataColumn(context, contentUri, null, null)
                                } catch (e: NumberFormatException) {
                                    //In Android 8 and Android P the id is not a number
                                    uri.path.replaceFirst("^/document/raw:", "").replaceFirst("^raw:", "")
                                }
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }

            }
```

Comment: You are on Android Q?

Comment: @blackapps i did not get it !

Comment: i will share you the code

Comment: i tried it with android 8.1.0